# multiple permissions in android:permisson

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have a requirement to parse the *AndroidManifest.xml* of an app to find out what permissions a client app need to possess in order to communicate with this app. As per [android developer guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#prmsn) the permission mentioned in the **android:permission** attribute of **application** tag and component (Activity, Service, Provider, Receiver) tag is supposed to be possessed by the client app. An example (AndroidManifest.xml excerpt) of this usage is

```
<application android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    ...
</application>
```

In the aforementioned example, the client app should possess **android.permission.INTERNET** in order to communicate with this app.

My question is, this permission information is mentioned in the attribute of a tag. Hence I understand (I might be wrong) it is **not possible to have more than one permission** to be mentioned here. But it is quite possible that an app/ component could expect the client app/ component to possess more than one such a permission. For example, in the aforementioned case, the app could expect both android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permissions to be possessed by the client app. But there seems to be no room to specify this in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Please let me know whether it is possible to mandate the possession of more than one permission by a client app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence I understand (I might be wrong) it is not possible to have more than one permission to be mentioned here

Correct.

> But there seems to be no room to specify this in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Correct.

> I have a requirement to parse the AndroidManifest.xml of an app to find out what permissions a client app need to possess in order to communicate with this app

Technically, this is not possible, as apps can check for permissions at runtime (e.g., by [calling `checkCallingPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingPermission%28java.lang.String%29)).

Comment: If I happened to see some permission like android.permission.INTERNET in the "android:permission" attribute of a <service> then can I assume that any component that communicates with this service has to possess android.permission.INTERNET permission? Or still I need to look at the code? I guess, in the code, the service could check for presence any permission other than android.permission.INTERNET (as it is already mandated through the AndroidManifest.xml. am I right?

Comment: @AnnamalaiN: "then can I assume that any component that communicates with this service has to possess android.permission.INTERNET permission?" yes, but the component may need other permissions as well, checked at runtime.

Comment: OK, I understand that only by looking at the **AndroidManifest.xml and the code** of a component we can conclude on the expected permissions from the client app (mere parsing of AndroidManifest.xml is not enough).

Comment: @AnnamalaiN: Correct.