# On checking for permissions dynamically in android apps

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions

Following up on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420994/multiple-permissions-in-androidpermisson) on android permissions enforcement at runtime, I found that there are many different ways in android which an app can verify the permissions possessed by the calling (client) app. This includes calls like checkCallingPermission, checkCallingOrSelfPermission, checkCallingUriPermission, checkCallingOrSelfUriPermission, checkPermission, checkUriPermission. As far as I have gone through the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), I am able to find only these calls pertaining to permissions check at run time. My questions:

- Is there any other way (rather than using the aforementioned calls)
  to check the permissions of a caller dynamically? If there are any
  such calls, please provide info/links or list them.
- The description of  [checkCallingOrSelfPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingOrSelfPermission%28java.lang.String%29) says

> it grants your own permissions if you are not currently processing an
>   IPC. Use with **care**!

**This seems risky as it could facilitate the delegation of (dangerous) permissions to the calling process which could result in privilege escalation** (if used carelessly). Please let me know whether I am right in saying that this could lead to privilege escalation attacks.

- I could not understand why a process (running app) would check whether **it** possesses certain permission (it would very well know what it is entitled to do?). Please let me know the
  intuition behind the design of this particular method:
  checkCallingOrSelfPermission. (Putting it simply, why/ when do I need
  checkCallingOrSelfPermission?)

Answer (score 3):

There are two type of permission check mechanism in Android.

One is runtime-dynamic checking per process, and the other one is static checking per package. What you mentioned is all about runtime-dynamic stuffs are implemented in Context, the another version is in PackageManager. - **[checkPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)**

What you want to is check whether a specific package has a specific permission, [checkPermission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the answer. For more detailed description, there is a article in Android Developer Site, about this subject. 
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#declaring

In many case you don't need to use dynamic permission checking methods, it is needed only if you are working one provider for sharing some private files to specific client, remote service or some widgets - something related temporally permission grant system via Intent or IPC.

And, one other thins for your previous question about [multiple permissions in android:permisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420994/multiple-permissions-in-androidpermisson). There is a way an app define the list of permissions what they want inside Manifest.

check-
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: Thanks. I am interested to know about communication between apps (involving IPC) and that too the permission checks that happen at run time (That's why I have named the question appropriately). I think the package level permissions is out this scope.

Comment: `And, one other thins for your previous question about multiple permissions in android:permisson. There is a way an app define the list of permissions what they want inside Manifest`
-
I have completely understood this - My previous question was not this simple and straight forward. It was about permission an app would require from a client app in order to have an IPC. I got a proper answer for that post.

Comment: i was just going through Api's.. and i found getPackageManager().addPermission(PermissionInfo). it says  A package can only add permissions to trees that were defined by either its own package or another with the same user id. and also says New permissions must be added before any .apks are installed that use those permissions.

Comment: but i did not use this api and not getting exactly what it does ? helpfull if i get a sample code to understand