# Exploiting checkCallingOrSelfPermission() for privilege escalation attack

Tags: android, android-permissions

I was going through checkCallingOrSelfPermission() in the Context class and wondering how it can be exploited; i.e. if some application triggers a method of the callee/your application which in turn calls checkCallingOrSelfPermission(), finally giving access to that permission to the other application, or releasing sensitive information that would otherwise require that permission.

This is what i understood after going through the Java Doc:

This method can be only exploited by any calling application which is in the same process of callee application. To get into the same process both the apps need to have the same shareuserid and process in the manifest file, in addition to also being signed by the same certificate.

So the calling application needs to do following.

1. Has to know under which process and shareuser id the callee application is running. (I'm not sure how feasible this is?)
2. Has to be signed with the same certificate that the callee application was signed with (unlikely assuming the certificate is kept safe).

Is this the method of exploitation that the checkCallingOrSelfPermission() documentation is warning against, or are there other (more realistic) ways that it could be exploited.

I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434972/on-checking-for-permissions-dynamically-in-android-apps), but the answer was not satisfactory.

Comment: "This method can be only exploited by any calling application which is in the same process of callee application" -- you would need to explain what this "exploit" is before anyone can tell you if the "exploit" is possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry if i was not clear enough...added description at the top to explain the exploitation..

Comment: "if any application calls a method of the callee/your application which in turn calls checkcallingorselfpermission at the end giving access to that permission to the other application" -- `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` does not grant anything to anyone.

Comment: @CommonsWare acc. to the java doc  This is the same as
     * {@link #checkCallingPermission}, except it grants your own permissions
     * if you are not currently processing an IPC.So would not an application running in the same process of callee application granted the permission when it calls this method ?

Comment: @CommonsWare the OP added more information since you initially replied; do you have any insight? I've added a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Under *normal* circumstances `Binder.callingPid() == Process.myPid()` holds. This changes when handling an IPC request, the system modifies the *calling PID* value stored by `Binder`, it assigns it to the PID of the caller app. However, this change **only affects the thread where the remotelly called method is executed**, in other threads the equality still holds. Therefore, if `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` is called in a such an unaffected thread, it will return `PERMISSION_GRANTED` (provided the service app holds that permission) and a leak (or other biblical consequences) may occur.

Alternatively, if `clearCallingIdentity()` is called before `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` the same issue can arise, although I believe it is less likely to happen.

Tested on Nexus 6P, Android 6.0.1 (MHC19I).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in the code.

**The checkCallingOrSelfPermission() is safe in IPC call.** Check out the implementation of `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` and `checkCallingPermission()` [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#1403). They both check the permission of the IPC client/the caller. **When the caller is from outside,they are exactly the same!**

If the caller is from inside(the same process), well, if some one can execute code inside your process, it's already exploited. No need to exploit use `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()` again.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all... The docs warn against using checkCalling OrSelf Permission(). Why? How could one exploit it?

Comment: @TimRae . Answer edited. checkCallingOrSelfPermission() is not exploitable,as far as I know.

Comment: Still doesn't really answer the question:  "The docs warn against using `checkCallingOrSelfPermission()`. Why?". Unless you're saying that the docs are wrong, which you would need to have a very deep understanding of Binder to say categorically.